# Appium android - find element by attribute

Tags: java, android, appium

I would like to assign a custom attribute to elements in the app's layout, and to write an automation test that locates elements by the given attribute.

for example, the layout contains:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="myId"
                android:background="..."
                android:my-attribute="myValue">
```

And I try to locate the element by:

```
 androidDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@my-attribute=\"myValue\"]");
```

However the driver fails to locate the element.

I also tried

```
 androidDriver.findElement(By.id("myId").getAttribute("my-attribute");
```

But I get null on getAttribute..

Is locating by attribute supported on android? Is it supported on Appium? If so, do I have a syntax mistake?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i cant post comments for now. Can you see `my-attribute` in the `uiautomatorviewer`? If you can then it should be possible but there are also features that is not supported depending on what android version you are using.

Comment: I can't see my-attribute in the ui automator viewer. I'm using android 6 (Marshmallow) SDK and emulator. Any ideas?

Comment: Appium uses uiautomatoviewer as a reference to which element or attribute to access. All I know is that, if you cant see it there you cant access it. But if you'd like some answers, I found this https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/5142. Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, I saw that one, was hoping that I was missing something. Thanks!